# Auth.currentUserInfo() is returning null response, when page reload

Tags: aws-amplify

I have used import { Auth } from 'aws-amplify'; in my react project. I have used below methods in my projects,

1. Auth.signIn(userName)
2. Auth.sendCustomChallengeAnswer(authUser, code)

The method Auth.currentUserInfo(); returns null value if I do page refresh.

Please help me how to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you'll need to `await` this request.

This code will log the user to the console.

```
useEffect(() => {
(async() => {
    const user = await Auth.currentUserInfo;
     console.log(user);
})();
}, [])
```